# Fancy Scrolling animation (like on Apple Airpods pro page)

Tags: javascript, scroll, dom-events, css-animations

I'm trying to create a scrolling  animation like on Apple Airpods pro page, by using multiple images.

[image]

But as you can see, I have an issue with all the images, and as I scroll I just have all the images staying on the screen...

There is my js file.

```
 const html = document.documentElement;
 const canvas = document.getElementById("hero-lightpass");
 const context = canvas.getContext("2d");

 const frameCount = 162;
 const currentFrame = index => (
    `images/Women${index.toString().padStart(4, '0')}.png`
    )

 const preloadImages = () => {
  for (let i = 1; i < frameCount; i++) {
     const img = new Image();
     img.src = currentFrame(i);
     }
  };

 const img = new Image()
 img.src = currentFrame(1);
 canvas.width=1158;
 canvas.height=770;
 img.onload=function(){
    context.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
  }

 const updateImage = index => {
    img.src = currentFrame(index);
    context.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
  }

  window.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
    const scrollTop = html.scrollTop;
    const maxScrollTop = html.scrollHeight - window.innerHeight;
    const scrollFraction = scrollTop / maxScrollTop;
    const frameIndex = Math.min(
      frameCount - 1,
       Math.ceil(scrollFraction * frameCount)
    );

    requestAnimationFrame(() => updateImage(frameIndex + 1))
  });

  preloadImages()`
```

Comment: You need to [clear](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/clearRect) the canvas each iteration

Comment: Consider using `<video>` and jumping to a frame instead, as loading and rendering loads of images will cause a browser to stutter.